# In a JPA query, how do I pass in a list for use as a single-column table?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a list of IDs, and I need a query to return only those that do not exist in the specified table. I know that, in SQL, you can do it like this:

```
select *
from ( 
   values (4),(5),(6)
) as v(id)
where not exists (select *
   from images i
   where i.id = v.id);
```

(From this answer: [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141137/11088))

But I'm attempting to use a JPA `@Query`, and pass in the list as a parameter, which it doesn't seem to like.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM :ids AS t(id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ([Nested select clause])
```

With

```
List<Long> findIdsMissingFromTable(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids, [...]
```

I have also tried `(VALUES :ids)`, which it also doesn't like, and removing the `AS` with the same result. In all cases, I get `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 18 [...]` which seems to be the colon in the first case, or the open parenthesis in the second.

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I don't think this is possible since I'd think that you cannot use bind variables in that place. Is there a table that does contain these Ids? What database are you using?

Comment: @JensSchauder I learned that afterwards, yes. The ids did not come from a table, but were passed in. This had to be a solution that worked for multiple different databases. Still, I figured it out, finally.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77971717/2886891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA queries do not allow subqueries outside of WHERE or HAVING clauses. The subquery in this case is `(VALUES :ids)`, because it makes a table the rest of the query can use. If it could be reorganised to have the subquery in the WHERE clause, the problem could be solved that way. However, setting `nativeQuery = true` was the simplest solution for my case, because I did not need any JPA-specific features like FETCH.

Answer (score -1):

I tried passing using the native query and values(:ids). It is picking only one id instead of all the passed id’s in the list. Did you do any additional steps to create the query

Comment: Hi and welcome. This site isn't a forum, it's just for questions and answers. Your comment will probably be deleted, because this is where answers go. You could instead open a new question (and reference this one). :)

Comment: Hi, I have created a new question, by any chance do you remember the soultion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74265107/in-a-jpa-query-how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-values-and-get-ids-which-are-not-present