# In a JPA query, How do i pass a list of values and get ids which are not present in the table?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have table called employee with id as columns. I want to query the database by providing the list of ids and get only the Id's which are not present in the database. I tried

```
@Query(value = "select id from (VALUES(:ids)) v(id) except (select id from employee)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public List<String> filterNonExistingEmployeeiIds(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

I tried passing using the native query and values(:ids). It is picking only one id instead of all the passed id’s in the list. Is there any way it picks all the values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL for Postgres should look like

```
select *
from unnest(array['id1','id2','id3', ...]) as t(id)
where id not in (select e.id from Employee as e);
```

I don't think you can write this in JPA or HQL (at least with Hibernate ORM 5), and I'm not sure if you can use parameters.

But, you can try this:

```java
@Query(
    value = "select * from unnest(array[:ids]) as t(id) where id not in (select id from Employee as e)",
    native=true)
public List<String> filterNonExistingEmployeeiIds(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

or you can create a string representing the list of ids and `string_to_array`:

```java
@Query(
    value="select * from unnest(string_to_array(:ids, ',')) as t(id) where id not in (select e.id from Employee as e)",
    native=true)
public List<String> filterNonExistingEmployeeiIds(@Param("ids") String ids);
...

List<String> ids = ...
String idsAsString = ids.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",");
List<String> nonExistingIds = repository.filterNonExistingEmployeeiIds(idsAsString);
```

If both these approaches won't work, you can create the query string yourself and use a custom repository:

```java
public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {
     
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
 
    @Override
    public List<String> filterNonExistingEmployeeiIds(List<String> ids) {
        String query = ... // create the query 
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, String.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: My table is very huge and this approach will end up fetching all the values from db and increase memory consumption.

Comment: I see, which db are you using?

Comment: postgres database

Comment: Similar question asked here but not sure what was the final solution. @AlbeyAmakiir, do you remember the solution.

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712226/in-a-jpa-query-how-do-i-pass-in-a-list-for-use-as-a-single-column-table

Comment: By the way, even if the table is huge, my approach will only return the ids that match the one in the parameter list. How big is the `ids` list ?

Comment: The list is of size greater than 1000 and this query is executed for every 30 secs.

Comment: I used the entity manager and executed the query. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> It is picking only one id instead of all the passed id’s in the list. Is there any way it picks all the values in the list?

Yes, it works at least in the reactive native query `org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query`, but I believe it would also work in the standard JPA.

There are two points:

1. The placeholder must not have the parenthesis around, so it must be `(VALUES :ids)` instead of <strike>`(VALUES (:ids))`</strike>

```java
@Query("select * from (VALUES :ids) as v(id)...")
```

2. You force the inner parenthesis around each ID `(VALUES (id1), (id2), (id3), ...)` by wrapping each element inside another array, so passing `Collection<Object[]> ids` instead of <strike>`Collection<String> ids`</strike>

```java
/** The internal implementation */
@Query("select * from (VALUES :ids) as v(id)...")
List<String> getMyValuesImpl(Collection<Object[]> ids);

/** The method with a nice signature */
default List<String> getMyValues(Collection<String> ids) {
    return getMyValuesImpl(ids.stream().map(id -> new Object[]{id}).toList());
}
```